# Can't open VS solution file in Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio

I have a new work laptop running Windows 10 and I installed Visual Studio Enterprise 2019.  When I first fired it up and tried to "Open Project Solution", and point it to a solution in Windows Explorer, the "Open" button is grayed out in Windows Explorer.

When I do the exact same thing on my old laptop it works fine, and opens the solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it happen with all solutions or just the one?  Can you create a new project and reopen it?  Are the versions of VS the same on both laptops?  What happens if you double click on the solution file in windows explorer?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot to help me understand which UI is disabled here?